# I can't get the redirect using URLSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-bootstrap, navigateurl, urlsearchparams

I'm trying to get the redirect option in '/login?redirect=/envio' but it always fail. I'm using new URLSearchParams(buscar).get('redirect') and when I use log to see if I got the redirect, i recibe null. Can someone help?

This is de URL I'm creating

```
const pagarHandler = () => {
   navigate('/login?redirect=/envio');
}
```

This is the code

```
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const buscar= useLocation();
    console.log(buscar);
    const redirectEnUrl = new URLSearchParams(buscar).get('redirect');
    console.log(redirectEnUrl);
    const redirect = redirectEnUrl ? redirectEnUrl : '/';
    console.log(redirect);
```

When the login is done, I use navigate to see if it's just a login or it was redirected to login because there wasan't a user, but it always redirects me to the home screen

`navigate(redirect || ('/'));`

Thanks and sorry for my English

EDIT:
Okay so I found a solution for anyone looking here with the same problem. Insted of using the useLocation(), I used this and it worked

```
const urlParams = window.location.search;
const redirectEnUrl = urlParams.get('redirect')
```